# Validate list item with javascript API

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, splistitem, validation

I want to develop a custom datasheet view to edit a list.

I add item through the javascript API. The problem is that the service doesn't control  fields value. For example : 
- I add an item with a mandatory field
- I don't fill the mandatory field
- I save
- The item is added to the list (no error from the webservice).

So, are there methods to control fields value ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make your validation on the field? It should be a simple if-statement in the javascript you use to add the item.

Comment: Yes I know but there are a lot of validation for one field and i have to validate all field type...